# Suppose $X$ has a standard normal distribution and $Y=e^X$. What is the $k^{\text{th}}$ moment of $Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, definite-integrals

My attempt
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y<y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\ln y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx $$
from $f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)$,
$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\ln y)^2}~~~(0<y<\infty) $$
so
$$ M_Y(t)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{ty}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\ln y)^2}dy$$
I'm not sure how to solve this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(Y^k) = E(e^{kX}) = M_{X}(k) = e^{\mu k + \frac{\sigma^2k^2}{2}}$$

Put $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$ if $X$ follows standard normal distribution.